# SWT Textfield right click executes outside textfield

Tags: java, swt, textfield

I have a Text for which I have a default context menu(copy,cut,paste) which is accessed with right click.

When I right click in the Text , drag the cursor outside the Text and release the right click the context menu is still displayed, but in the point where the cursor was released.

Is there a method for resolving this issue?

Comment: What does your existing code look like (MCVE)? Have you tried anything to solve the problem?

Comment: `TextField` is not a SWT widget, you mean `Text`? Also what you described seems to be the OS default behavior (at least in Windows). Why you need to change it?